# C# dependecies aren't being included with publish

Tags: c#, dependencies, .net-core, publish

I'm trying to publish a web API built in .NET Core to a Ubuntu server but am having difficulty with the dependencies. I am new to doing this in C# and haven't found a concise answer to how dependencies are included with the publish command. I was lead to believe that they were complied into a `.dll` but I am getting this error when running my app

```
Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (api.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Newtonsoft.Json', version: '11.0.2'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

Shouldn't that have been included in the "Release" directory after being published?

I'm using .NET Core on a Mac and then publishing to an Ubuntu sever should that affect anything here.

**.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your `.csproj` file. The fact that the path begins with `lib` is suspicious - aren't you using NuGet to include `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: I added the dependency with VS, doesn't that run NuGet for you or a background process that gets the dependency? Local running from VS works a-o-k

Comment: Again, please show the `.csproj` file of the library in question. Without it, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @NightOwl888 should be added now

Comment: @recursivePython, I'm guessing I know what this is but to confirm; do you have access to the remote server? If so, after publish, can you look at the bin and see if Newtonsoft.Json.dll is in there? I'm guessing it is. Can you confirm its version?

Comment: @NightOwl888 it's not in the release directory inside of bin. Where should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't that have been included in the "Release" directory after being published?

No.

When you publish a project, you specify a different directory for the publish output when creating the publish profile.

[image]

The Release directory is only for assets that are used during debugging. During development, the NuGet dependencies are not in the Release folder, they are in the NuGet cache. So, you cannot always just copy the Release folder and expect it to run.

After publishing, the entire application (including all dependencies) are output to the publish location. Do note that the publish output doesn't necessarily have to be a folder. For example, depending on the type of project it may be published to IIS with web deploy or to an FTP location.